Is Replit suitable for the Stack Exchange Network?
Recently, Replit shut down their support forum, Replit Ask, now linking to Stack Overflow. As a result, many users with Replit-specific problems are now posting questions which aren't about code and are downvoted and then closed.
With this, I was wondering if it would be appropriate to redirect Replit users to another Stack Exchange-affiliated site, such as Super User, Unix & Linux (repls use NixOS), or Server Fault, or if vendor-specific help such as that related to Repl configuration is not suitable for the network.

Might be good/helpful to give a quick overview of what replit is in the question

A vendor/product specific forum can't be replaced by a stack exchange site, let alone multiple. That needs specific guidance at the vendor/product site before their audience is sent-off to any SE site. Currently their care for doing the right thing isn't on par and needs fixing first: see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/how-can-i-use-stack-overflow-to-support-our-developer-community/326375#326375 and linked questions (sidebar on the right)

That's a fatal mistake by Replit. Stack Overflow is not a support forum, and from quick glance, most recent Replit questions there got closed and/or downvoted. Essentially, it can easily lead to end of the product as frustrated people who won't get help will spread the news and nobody will keep using it. And rightly so, IMO. (And neither is any SE site - that is not what Stack Exchange is for)

@ShadowWizard Replit isn't going away, it's very popular. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replit (I'm not a fan, though).

@PM2Ring well, it'll surely lose users, and frustrate existing users. Typical for companies that start small, and become too big, I guess.

Related question on MSO: Please reach out to Replit regarding outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow

Issues with using/configuring Replit are on-topic for Stack Overflow, since that is a software tool primarily used by programmers. However, questions have to be otherwise on-topic for Stack Overflow, and they have to be well asked. If they are not either of these things, then they will be poorly received, and will likely end up downvoted and closed. In this sense, it is no different from asking a question how to use/configure Visual Studio, Eclipse, or any other traditional development environment.
Questions about problems that only Replit technical support can solve are off-topic for Stack Overflow. For example, if the service is temporarily down, or your account has been disabled, or you have a billing question, or something like that, that is not permitted to be asked on Stack Overflow because the community cannot help you.
Note that Replit still has a way to submit a support ticket to their customer service team, which is what you would want to use for these types of issues:

There is also a "Status" page linked there, which should eliminate the need to ask questions about the site's availability.
Their "Support policy" page also suggests that there is a support@replit.com email address for use by free users to get help with their account.
Feature requests for Replit are also off-topic for Stack Overflow, mainly because they are not questions. (If phrased as a question—i.e., "Can I do x on Replit?"—then that would almost certainly be on-topic. The answers might run the gamut from "yes, and here's how", to "no, unfortunately that is not possible", to "no, not yet, but they announced on their blog that they are working on adding it soon".)

Useful reference- Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?
